# How to search for nodes that don't have parents in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

Very simply, I want the nodes at the top, and I have lots of disjoint subgraphs in my graph and I want the nodes at the top of those subgraphs, i.e. without any parents.

Tried a number of things but can't get a handle on what to do. Negative queries seems non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a pattern like `(parent)-[:CHILD]->(child)` then the top nodes are nodes that don't have incoming :CHILD relationships:

```
MATCH (top) // though you should use labels if possible)
WHERE NOT ()-[:CHILD]->(top)
...
```

And if you're using a relationship in the opposite direction (`(parent)<-[:PARENT]-(child)`) then it will be a similar query, just apply the relationship in the other direction:

```
MATCH (top) // though you should use labels if possible)
WHERE NOT (top)-[:PARENT]->()
...
```

Since your predicates is only based on the relationship type and direction (notice we don't need to know anything about the node at the other end of the pattern) the planner can use a degree check on relationships on the node by type/direction, which is more efficient than having to expand the relationships found.